# ifelse function usage in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to use the ifelse function (similar to ternary operators in other languages) in R to evaluate an expression that if done correctly, will save me the need to generate many if/else statements. My code is below:

```
library(ggtree)
library(tidyverse)

tree <- read.tree(text='(((((((A:4,B:4):6,C:5):8,D:6):3,E:21):10,((F:4,G:12):14,H:8):13):13,((I:5,J:2):30,(K:11,L:11):2):17):4,M:56);')


Accession1 <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M')
Column1 <- c('10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '110', '120', '130')

dd = data.frame(Accession1, Column1)
print(dd)

p <- ggtree(tree) + ylim(-1, NA) + theme_tree2() 

p <- p %<+% dd

dd$Column1 <- as.numeric(dd$Column1) 

col = "Column1"
to_map = "Column1"
assign(col, dd[[to_map]])

p <- p + geom_tippoint(aes(colour = ifelse(col == "NULL", NULL, !!sym(col))))
#p <- p + geom_tippoint(aes(colour = Column1))

ggsave("debug_tree.png")
```

I hope to achieve the output:[as displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlFFc.png)

However, I achieve this output instead: `[bad_output][2]`

The offending line is:
`p <- p + geom_tippoint(aes(colour = ifelse(col == "NULL", NULL, !!sym(col))))` 
So if col is "NULL", I would like colour to be equal to NULL (and not be plotted), alternatively, I would like it to be !!sym(col) such that it can be plotted but this is not working. I would like to know why that is the case, alternatively, is there a better way of modifying the line above such that I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same `length` and `NULL` have a length of 0.

```
length(NULL)
#[1] 0
```

We may need `if/else`

```
if(col == "NULL") NULL else sym(col)
```

Based on the description, the condition can be outside and there is no need for an `else` if we use `!=` to update the 'p' object

```
if(col != "NULL")
     p <- p + geom_tippoint(aes(colour = !! sym(col)))
  }
```